# Nginx configuration is not working, redirecting all sub domain requests to main domain

Tags: nginx

I have a problem with my Nginx. More specifically I have added several sub domains and the problem is that as it enters the sub domain, it redirects to the main domain. My configuration is as below.

Extracted from [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/iKsjQ9wX):

```
Main config:
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
     

        root /var/www/intogame.pl/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        client_max_body_size 200M;

        server_name intogame.pl;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                
        }
}
Second domain config:
###Głowna strona thwork.pl
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    client_max_body_size 200M;

    root /var/www/thwork.pl;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    
    server_name thwork.pl www.thwork.pl;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?download=$1;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                
        }
}


Sub domain config:


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    client_max_body_size 200M;


    root /var/www/intogame.pl/imghost;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    
    server_name host.intogame.pl;

    location / {
            rewrite ^/([^/]+)$ /index.php?download=$1;
        
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?download=$1;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                
        }


}


Nginx config:
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 66536;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    server_name_in_redirect on;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log on;
    error_log on;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

> Server: nginx/1.6.2
> Date: Thu, 15 Jun 2017 08:08:18 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> Connection: keep-alive
> Vary: Accept-Encoding

Comment: Can you paste the output of `curl -IL http://host.intogame.pl` into your original question?

Comment: sure, added to orginal question